# Family of funcitons that approximates uniform density on an ellipsoid

Tags: probability-distributions, approximation-theory

Given an nondegerate ellipsoid $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, described as $E = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^d: (x-x_0)^TQ_0(x-x_0)\leq 1\}$ and let $\chi_E$ be the characteristic function supported on $E$. I am thinking about how to construct a family $\{f_n:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}\}_{n= 1}^\infty$, where each $f_n$ can be written as a smooth expression in terms of $Q_0, x_0$ and $n$, such that, as $n\to\infty$,  $f_n\to\chi_E$ in $L^p$, for all $p\geq 1$. I have googled related key words but found nothing. Any advice or related reference would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good ways to accomplish this. One is by using the logistic function $L$, defined by the formula 
$$L(u):=\frac1{1+e^{-u}}.$$
Then 
$$g_n(u):=L(n(1-u))
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\uparrow1&\text{ if }0\le u<1,\\
\downarrow0&\text{ if }u>1  
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
as $n\to\infty$. 
So, assuming that $Q_0$ is positive definite, letting 
$$f_n(x):=g_n((x-x_0)^TQ_0(x-x_0))  
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$, and using (say) the dominated convergence, we conclude that $f_n$ converges to the characteristic function of the set $E$ in $L^p$ for each $p\ge1$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks, I think the idea here is to observe that $1-(x-x_0)^TQ_0(x-x_0)$ is + if $x\in E$ and - if $x\notin E$. Thus, intuitively, it suffices to find $g_n$ such that $g_n(+)\to 1$ and $g_n(-)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.